# Transfer licenses into another Craft ID account

Tags: craft-id

I could only transfer licenses that were not yet assigned to any other Craft ID account. But how can I transfer the licenses, which are assigned with my other Craft ID account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to release the license in your Craft ID account:
https://id.craftcms.com/account/licenses/cms

After that you will be able to claim the license in your other Craft ID account:
https://id.craftcms.com/account/licenses/claim

Comment: As I have described it, this only seems to work if the licenses are not assigned to another account yet, at least via 'Claim licenses by your email address'. Maybe it is possible manually?

Comment: That's why you have to release the license. Once you release it you can claim it to any other ID again. It won't get lost.